# Proving the convergnce of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

So, I have to prove that the sequence defined as 
$a_{n+1}=\frac{6(1+a_n)}{7+a_n}$ converges and then find the limit.

I have few questions; Do i have to assume that $a_n \geq 0$ or $a_n \leq0$. Because if i assume that $a_n \geq 0$, I can prove that

$\left|a_{n+1}-2\right| \leq \frac{4}{7}\left|a_{n}-2\right|$, and by induction, it would be easy to show that $a_n \to 2$.

Any help would be appreciated. Is there a way to prove convergence without knowing the signs of $a_n$?

Comment: You should first find the candidate limit because you have to do it, anyway, and it's in fact simpler than to prove the existence of the limit. If there is a limit, what can you say about $a_{n+1}-a_n$ for a large enough $n$? What does it imply?

Comment: @LubošMotl I know how to use monotone convergence theorem, i am just curious about the signs of $a_n$, because nothing is given about that in the original problem

Comment: Have you tried to find the change of the distances from the -3 fixed point, just like you did for +2? One always gets attracted to +2, and repelled from -3, so one ends up with the constant sequence at -3 and the same limit if you start with -3. Otherwise, even for -2.99 or -3.01, you will end up with +2.

Comment: @LubošMotl I can see that but i don't know how to do it, e.g. what happens if $a_0=-5$?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an easier way to find what value the limit converges to, consider that by the definition of convergence, as $n\to\infty$, $a_{n+1} = a_n$.

Thus, let's let $a_{n+1} = a_n = L$.

Substituting this in, we get:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{6(1+a_n)}{7+a_n}$$
$$L = \frac{6(1+L)}{7+L}$$
$$L = \frac{6 + 6L}{7+L}$$
$$7L + L^2 = 6 + 6L$$
$$L ^2 + L - 6 = 0$$
$$(L+3)(L-2) = 0$$

Therefore, $L = -3, 2$

Since all of the terms in this sequence are positive, $L = -3$ s an extraneous solution.

Therefore, the sequence converges to $2$.

As for proving that the sequence converges, assume that $a_n \ge 0$ and use induction.

Comment: "Since all of the terms in this sequence are positive" How?

Answer (score 2):

**Convergence:** Note that $$a_{n+1}=6-\frac{36}{7+a_n}$$

The function $\displaystyle f(x) = 6 - \frac{36}{7+x}$ has derivative $\displaystyle f'(x) =  \frac{36}{(7+x)^2}.$ So we have $0 \leq f'(x) <1$ so the sequence converges by the [Contraction Mapping Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem).

Comment: The inequality $f'(x)\lt1$ does not hold for all $x$.  For example, $f'(-6)=36$.  And things get really bad at $x=-7$.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to make *some* assumption, because the sequence does *not* converge in all cases.  For example, if you specify $a_0=-463/133$ as a starting value, then (if my arithmetic is correct) $a_1=-55/13$, $a_2=-7$, and $a_3$ is undefined.

It's easy to show that there is an infinite sequence of such "bad" starting values, and it's possible to show that that sequence converges to $-3$ (which is the "extraneous solution" in Varun Iyer's answer).  Any statement that the original sequence converges must, at the very least, include a condition that rules out these "bad" values.  The simplest such condition is to say $a_0\ge0$, which clearly implies $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score -4):

As Varun showed, the fixed points obeying $L=6(1+L)/(7+L)$ are $+2$ and $-3$. For $a_0\gt -3$, one may see that one is getting close to $L=+2$. For $a_0\gt -3$, the subsequent terms are getting more negative, but they inevitably drop below $a_n\lt -7$ at some point, and for $a_0\lt -7$, $a_1$ may already be calculated to be positive i.e. $a_1\gt - 3$, because the graph of $y=6(1+x)/(7+x)$ is a hyperbola, and one starts to converge towards the limit $L=2$, anyway.

As Arpit wrote, Contraction Mapping Theorem guarantees the existence of a limit. The fixed points $L=+2$ and $L=-3$ are the only possible limits. And the sequence diverges away from $L=-3$ for almost all $a_0$. The only exception occurs when $a_0=-3$ when all $a_n=-3$ and $L=-3$ is also the limit. For all other values of $a_0$, the limit has to be $L=+2$.